# Construction an a command line bash script with spaces in path names

Tags: bash, quoting

I need a simple script to call gcc but I've got a long list of libraries that I need to pass to it in a directory who's path has a space on it.

In place of gcc for testing my script I've used:

```
#!/bin/bash
for var in "$@"
do
    echo "$var"
done
```

This is one of the umpteen attempts I've tried:

```
#!/bin/bash
LIBDIR="lib dir"
LIBS=
LIBS+="lib1 "
LIBS+="lib2 "
CMD="./debug.sh "
for LIB in $LIBS
do
    CMD+="-I ${LIBDIR}/${LIB} " 
done
${CMD}
exit
```

Obviously the problem is that bash cannot tell which spaces are meant to separate the arguments and which are not, but no matter how I place quotes or backslashes I cannot figure out how to 'quote' some of the spaces and not the others.

Answer (score 2):

For your particular case:

```
#!/bin/bash
LIBDIR="lib dir"
LIBS=("lib1" "lib2")
CMD=(./debug.sh)
for LIB in "${LIBS[@]}"
do
    CMD+=(-I "${LIBDIR}/${LIB}")
done
"${CMD[@]}"
exit
```

There are two arrays in use: `LIBS` for the library names, and `CMD` for the command itself. This will also work if there are *other* extra spaces. `+=(...)` concatenates the new items onto the end of an array, just like it concatenates the new string onto the end of a string. `"${CMD[@]}"` expands to all the values of the array *as individual words* (not split on spaces). [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters) has more on the subject in general, and [How can we run a command stored in a variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/444946/how-can-we-run-a-command-stored-in-a-variable) in the specific.